# Git init não criou branch master

Tags: git

Eu estou tentando dar um `git init` no meu projeto, ele retorna com sucesso:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/myprojetPath/.git/
```

Mas porque quando eu digito `git branch`, ele não retorna nenhum branch?

```
$ git branch

(Não retorna nenhum branch)
myuser@WKS054 MINGW64 myprojetPath (master)
$
```

Mas no meu terminal (Git bash, na verdade) mostra que estou no branch master.

Porêm quando eu troco de branch, não consigo voltar para branch master com `git checkout master`, ele informa que o branch não existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que quando se acaba de criar um repositório isso é comum.

Fiz alguns testes aqui e só aparece o branch quando fiz o seguinte:

```
git init
touch um_arquivo_incial
git add um_arquivo_inicial
git commit -am "Primeiro commit"
```

Depois, se você fizer `git branch`, então verá:

```
 >*master
```

Comment: Eu acho que é isso mesmo, eu dei o primeiro commit, agora esta tudo normal! muito obrigado mesmo